# Unreal Engine - Running instead of walking

Tags: animation, graph, unreal-engine4, blueprint, unreal-blueprint

I'm trying to animate a dragon and it keeps running it nevers walk i don't know why. Please tell me if you need anything else.
[image]

[image: https://www.zupimages.net/up/21/07/vk86.png]

[image: https://www.zupimages.net/up/21/07/aiwc.png]

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

In your dragon character blueprint there will be a component named 'character movement'. Inside that you will find max walk speed. So the thing happening here is when you press move forward axis input the value goes from 0 to your max walk speed which is your run speed. So that's why in your animation blueprint it is running directly.
What you have to do is set the default walk speed in 'character movement' component to your WALK speed. and when you press sprint button like 'Shift' you have to set the walk speed to higher number and when you release shift you have to set back to normal walk speed.

Answer (score 0):

Creature is so big that the max speed have to be increased.